# How do I open git-bash.exe from command prompt such that it executes "git status" automatically and waits for the next command instead of exiting

Tags: bash, git, command-line, git-bash

How can I create a git-bash shortcut which opens git-bash.exe and automatically runs "git status" and/or "git worktree list" at startup and then waits for my next command(s). I have tried:

- `".\git-bash.exe" -c "git status"` but the git-bash window closes immediately after executing git status
- `".\git-bash.exe" -c "git status;read"`, but this way it runs git status, waits for the enter key and closes the git-bash window

Comment: `.\git-bash.exe -c "git status;read;/bin/bash"`?

Comment: I'd probably use a `.bashrc` startup thingy that tests for "should I run `git status` during start-up", e.g., `[ "$DO_INITIAL_GIT_STATUS" = "yes" ] && git status`, and then set the environment variable `DO_INITIAL_GIT_STATUS` to `yes` to make that happen. (But since I just live in the shell all the time there's no point for me to do that.) @eftshift0's suggestion could also work but consider `git status && exec /bin/bash -i` (or the Windows equivalent) as the command to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the command 'exec $SHELL' to spawn a new interactive shell after your git commands exit. For example:

```
".\git-bash.exe" -c 'git status;exec $SHELL'
```